# Sum values from nested dictionary - Python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, sum

Say I have the following dictionary

```
counts = 
 {(0, 0): {'00': 0, '01': 4908, '10': 0, '11': 5092},
 (0, 1): {'00': 0, '01': 5023, '10': 0, '11': 4977},
 (1, 0): {'00': 0, '01': 5058, '10': 0, '11': 4942},
 (1, 1): {'00': 0, '01': 4965, '10': 0, '11': 5035}}
```

and I want to sum counts[0,0] and counts [0, 1]to get

```
idealcounts = {'00': 0, '01': 9931, '10': 0, '11': 10069}
```

How do I extract the counts[0,r] values and then sum them all up?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Unclear, Can you explain it a bit more

Comment: The dictionary 'counts' has 2 keys in its argument ie counts[k , r]
I want to sum all the values for counts[0 , r] cycling through all values of r and summing the values in the nested dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and update it with the sub-dictionaries you want:

```
from collections import Counter

data = {
    (0, 0): {'00': 0, '01': 4908, '10': 0, '11': 5092},
    (0, 1): {'00': 0, '01': 5023, '10': 0, '11': 4977},
    (1, 0): {'00': 0, '01': 5058, '10': 0, '11': 4942},
    (1, 1): {'00': 0, '01': 4965, '10': 0, '11': 5035}
}

counts = Counter()

for k in ((0, 0), (0, 1)):
    counts.update(Counter(data[k]))

print(counts)
# Counter({'00': 0, '01': 9931, '10': 0, '11': 10069})
```

Comment: As a note to OP, `update` is important here, if you use `+` or `+=` to update the global counter, then the elements with a count of `0` will not show up

Comment: What if I wanted to cycle over many keys ie data[0 , r] but r now is not restricted to 0 an 1 but is a long list of values.

Comment: @ZohimChandani the construct `for k in ((0, 0), (0, 1))` allows you to put any sort of list or iterator after the `in`. You just need a way to define exactly what you want there. Maybe that’s a different question?